# Loading JSON via $http. Works in Browser but not on Android (Device or Emulator)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I just started learning ionic framework and angular js to develop an android app. I wanted to write APOD viewer (=Astronomy Picture of the Day).

I do an api call to: https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&hd=true

wich returns a JSON string. then i view the picture (from the "hdurl" field).

everything works as expected when i try it in my browser. but when i build the app and run it in the emulator or on my phone it seems like i dont get an answer to my $http() call.

here is my code:

```
$scope.apodImgUrl = "img/loading.gif";
$scope.apiUrl = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&hd=true";
$http({
  method: "GET",
  url: $scope.apiUrl
}).then(function (response){
  if(response == null) {
    showError($location, "No Data", "Received nothing!");
  }else{
    if(response.data.media_type == "image") {
      $scope.apodImgUrl = response.data.hdurl;
    }else{
      showError($location, "No Image", "Only Images are Supported (so far!)");
    }
  }
},function (errorResponse) {
  showError($location, "HTTP GET Error", errorResponse);
});
```

I don't get an error neigther the image. it just shows me my loading.gif.

I have allready used the cordova whitelist plugin and added:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

to my config.xml.

I also have tried to add a proxy to my ionic.project file:

```
"proxies": [
  {
    "path": "/planetary/apod",
    "proxyUrl": "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod"
  }
]
```

I have also tried lots of different combinations how to call $http. (f.e. `$http.get().success().error()` or `$http.get().then()` or the plain `$http()`). with the same result.

any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your app using [Chrome inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en)?

Comment: hi @Phonolog, thanks for your reply, i am going to try it todays evening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add whitelist plugin in your project.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist --save
```

That will enable http request in your android device. And also check your android AndroidManifest.xml.It needs this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

at the last add these lines in your config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Then your http request will work correctly thanks.

Comment: hi, i tried it on a completely new project and it worked. i than analyzed the differences and it turned out that the line `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2"/>` was missing from my config.xml file. i added it and it worked! seems like `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist` doesn't add it and `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist --save` does. thanks a lot!

Comment: #linluk Thank for appreciation Bro .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem . And after adding whitelist plugin my problem stayed the same.Finally I solved it by commenting this line    `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">` . This line is in index.html page .